# Download a file and push into MySQL without timing out in Python

Tags: python

I download a big CSV distant file and want to push all lines into MySQL as they come in. I use `csv.reader` to parse the distant file. I add the lines into MySQL by batches of 1000.

The problem is that the connection with the peer times out after 5 minutes and though the file could be downloaded within less than one minute, pushing into MySQL takes more than that.

Is there a way to have the download job and the push jobs working asynchronously so the connection with the peer does not wait for mySQL constraints?

I want to avoid

1. downloading the full file in memory if not needed
2. starting to push into mysql as soon as the first line is downloaded
3. having to mess with temporary files

Basically, I want my python script to do something like `curl file | my_script_that_pushes_values.sh`.

Here is an illustration of what I do:

```
csvReader = csv.reader(distantfile)
valuesBuffer = []
for row in csvReader:
  valuesBuffer.append(getValues(row))
  if len(valuesBuffer) % 1000 = 0:
    pushValuesIntoMySQL(valuesBuffer)
    valuesBuffer = []
pushValuesIntoMySQL(valuesBuffer)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would copy whole file to your server and then use [`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) since it supports csv input:

```sql
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.txt' INTO TABLE tbl_name
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
  IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

---

If you don't like this solution you could use [`mysql_ping()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-ping.html) (hopefully connector you're using supports it) to *auto* reconnect.

> Checks whether the connection to the server is working. If the connection has gone down and auto-reconnect is enabled an attempt to reconnect is made. If the connection is down and auto-reconnect is disabled, mysql_ping() returns an error.

---

And if you have problem that you'd be able to download file but it times out because of delay of MySQL, you can run it in [two threads](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/threading.html) and sync it trough [`queue`](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/queue.html):

```python
# Prepare queue and end signaling handler
q = queue.Queue()
done = threading.Event()

# Function that fetches items from q and puts them into db after
# certain amount is reached
def store_db():
    items=[]

    # Until we set done
    while not done.is_set():
        try:
            # We may have 500 records and thread be done... prevent deadlock
            items.append(q.get(timeout=5))
            if len(items) > 1000:
                insert_into(items)
                items = []
            q.task_done()
         # If you wait longer then 5 seconds < exception
         except queue.Empty: pass

    if items:
        insert_into(items)

# Fetch all data in a loop
def continous_reading():
    # Fetch row
    q.put(row)

# Start storer thread
t = threading.Thread(target=store_db)
t.daemon = True
t.start()

continous_reading()
q.join() # Wait for all task to be processed
done.set() # Signal store_db that it can terminate
t.join() # to make sure the items buffer is stored into the db
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately it won't work in my case. The timeout is with the distant server that serves the csv, which I don't have control on, not with my MySQL DB. Plus I need to do some post processing in the CSV before pushing it (hidden in `getValues()` in my example).

Comment: For some reason, the part outside `while not done.is_set()` is never executed despite verifying `done.is_set() == true`. Do you see a reason why? Shouldn't I wake the thread up right after `done.set()`before exiting?

Comment: Answering my own comment, adding `t.join()` at the end fixed your piece of code. I hope you didn't mind I edited it for future readers.

Comment: @MadEchet ah, my bad. On windows thread even if marked as daemon won't get killed. Therefore I just forgot to add that sync piece :) Thanks.